# Navigation icon images

Tags: css

So I'd like to use some icon images for my site navigation. Currently I'm doing the following using the HTML5 Nav tag

```
<nav>
    <a href="index.html"><img src="images/whatever.png"/></a>
    <a href="dash.html"><img src="images/whatever.png"/></a>
    </nav>
```

For best practices I'd prefer not to have images in the html so I'm wondering if the correct way around this would be to give each link a pseudo class like;

```
    <nav>
    <a class="home" href="index.html"></a>
    <a class ="dash" href="dash.html"></a>
    </nav>
```

And then give each link a background image like;

```
.home {
    background-image: url(../whatever.png);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
<nav>
    <a class="home" href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a class="dash" href="dash.html">Dash</a>
</nav>
```

with the css like this:

```
nav a {
  display:inline-block; //so you can set width and height
  text-indent:-999em; //to hide the text
}
.home {
    background-image: url(../whatever.png);
    width: 100px; //image width
    height: 50px; /image height
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a sprite sheet to save on filesize and image requests. (This [CSS Sprite Generator](http://spritegen.website-performance.org/) is useful in generating sprite images).

So with this code:

```
<nav>
  <a class="home" href="index.html">Home</a>
  <a class="dash" href="dash.html">Dash</a>
</nav>
```

And assuming your images are 100px X 50px:

```
nav a { 
  /* whatever positioning rules or floats you need for the links */
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
} 

.home { background: url(iconsprite.png) 0 0 no-repeat; }
.dash { background: url(iconsprite.png) 0 -100 no-repeat; }
```

Where `0 0` and `0 -100` are the x and y coordinates of the top left corner of the image in the sprite sheet.

Comment: Thanks guys. @Nathan that's a handy Sprite Generator tool.